# What is the type for a Vue prop when declared in an array?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an existing Vue component with multiple props which are declared in an array without types:

```
props: ["prop1", "prop2"]
```

I'd now like to add a new prop with the type `Boolean`. This requires me to change the array to an object and set the type for the existing properties.

```
props: {
   "prop1": ???,
   "prop2": ???,
   "newProp": Boolean
}
```

What type do I need to choose in place of `???` so that nothing is changed in regards to those props? I assume `Object`, but I can't find any documentation to confirm that.

Comment: What is the actual type of those props?

Comment: @StarkButtowski They don't have a (declared) type and that's how I'd like to keep it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what `prop1` and `prop2` will be, based on the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation) you can pass `null` or `undefined` to make it `any` type.

```js
props: {
   "prop1": null,
   "prop2": null,
   "newProp": Boolean
}
```

Or if you already know what type of `prop1` and `prop2` will be, you can pass a type instead.

> The type can be one of the following native constructors:
>
> - String
> - Number
> - Boolean
> - Array
> - Object
> - Date
> - Function
> - Symbol

From: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Type-Checks

Comment: Ah, they hid the `null`/`undefined` option in a code sample. It's not mentioned in the API documentation. Thank you!